# How to convert LaTeX to expression without interpreting variables as products?

Tags: evaluation, string-manipulation, latex

I need to convert some LaTeX code to mathematica expressions. So far I have used

```
ToExpression["ab", TeXForm]
```

yielding `ab`, i.e. mathematica variable with the name "ab". This is what I want. However, the LaTeX code I would like to convert may be e.g. "2 ab".
Using

```
ToExpression["2 ab", TeXForm]
```

then returns `2 a b`, i.e. a product of `a` and `b`. How can I avoid this?

Comment: You can't avoid it. LaTeX is for typesetting, not for the accurate representation of math. The standard way to write $a$ times $b$ in LaTeX is simply `ab`. Some people may mean something different by `ab`, which shows that LaTeX is ambiguous, and meant to produce something readable by people, not by computers. Personally I wouldn't use `ab` in LaTeX ... I would use `\text{ab}` to enforce upright letters ... since frankly $ab$ would be read as a product by most people as well unless you actually spell out a recognizable word like $word$ ...

Comment: And `ToExpression["\\text{ab}", TeXForm]` does import as you'd expect.  The tl;dr is: don't use LaTeX to represent math meant to be interpreted by computers!

Comment: What will you do with the Latex generated?  i..e is it supposed to be rendered as math environment? This is the typical usage. If so, in Latex spaces make no difference. Try to compile latex `$a    b$` and `$ab$` and you will see these give same exact output.  But if you really want `ab` to remain stuck to each others, why not do `TeXForm[ToExpression["2 ab"]]` ? This gives `2 \text{ab}`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I see now that the problem is not well posed. I'll try to find a work around.